# Low DPI images are not fully shown in WPF Image

Tags: wpf, image, stretch

So I have an UserControl that contains an image

```
 <StackPanel>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="RenderingImage" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0,0"  Stretch="None" Source="{Binding}" RenderTransform="{Binding}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Everything works fine as long as the image displayed is 96 or above. For smaller DPI images, for some reason the Image components crops the image

[image]

This is the full image and when I try to display it in the image component
[image]
It crops the right side.

Specifically this image is 72dpi. Is there any way I can avoid this, except changing the Stretch? Changing the Stretch to Fill/Uniform seems to work, but that changes the way I implemented zoom and other events for this specific UC. I would like to avoid that. It is also important that I preserves the original size of the image, and stretching obviously won't help me with that.

Comment: Assuming `source` is the original BitmapSource, what if you use `new TransformedBitmap(source, new ScaleTransform(source.DpiX / 96, source.DpiY / 96))` for the Image's Source?

Comment: @Clemens this won't help, it changes the Scale of the image. I already do that for zooming purposes. It still won't fit the hole bitmap into the image component.

Comment: It won't change the scale of the Image element, just that of its Source bitmap. However, we would of course need more details about what you are actually doing in order to be able to provide any help.

Comment: @Clemens what details you would like to know, I can give you. I have an UserControl that takes an Image (WritableBitmap) and allows user to perform zoom on the image. I use the ScaleX/ScaleY for the zooming.

Comment: @Clemens I've tried your solution and it works, can you please detail it a bit, I have no clue why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native width and height of a "device independent pixel" in WPF 1/96 inch - i.e. WPF draws with 96 DIP/inch or DPI.

If you load a bitmap with a different DPI, the BitmapSource is scaled to 96 DPI, i.e. its Width and Height properties are set to

```
bitmap.Width  = bitmap.PixelWidth  * 96 / bitmap.DpiX
bitmap.Height = bitmap.PixelHeight * 96 / bitmap.DpiY
```

These values are used for the size of the Image element when Stretch is set to `None`.

---

In order to compensate for this scaling, you may created a bitmap that reverses the scaling, e.g. by applying an appropriate ScaleTransform to the Transform property of a TransformedBitmap.

```
var scaled = new TransformedBitmap(bitmap,
    new ScaleTransform(bitmap.DpiX / 96, bitmap.DpiY / 96));
```

You are thus making sure that the scaled bitmap's Width and Height always equals its PixelWidth and PixelHeight.